# Deploying/Installing Self Hosted SignalR Windows Service to Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, windows-services, signalr, windows-server-2012

I'm at the final stages of building a framework for a custom CMS which leverage's SignalR to do some magic.

I have this running perfect in a console application but it's less than desirable in a production environment. So I've decided to port the code over to a Windows Service which was not particularly difficult but in all reality there's scattered information on deploying and installing.

There seems to be multiple SO posts and numerous developer articles but they never seem to cover the whole topic. As Windows Service's are very much alien to me, I was hoping someone could break down how this is done. Hopefully should provide a great resource for others.

So key questions:

1. What is the best directory for a window service to live?
2. How do you install? (Double click the exe)?
3. How do you run the service once installed?
4. Will SignalR permanently run in the background?

For the sanity of the post I'll add some code:

```
   public partial class SignalRService : ServiceBase
    {
        IDisposable SignalR;
        public SignalRService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://localhost:8080";
            SignalR = WebApp.Start(url); 
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            SignalR.Dispose();
        }
    }

 //Main that starts the service
 static void Main()
   {
      ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
      ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
       { 
         new SignalRService() 
       };
     ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
```

I would be extremely grateful, if anyone could clarify these key points and  centralize a resource for other's to view.

Regards,

Comment: Just curious, why not IIS as a host?

Comment: @Wasp Due to the current architecture off the system, it follows a pattern of decoupled systems. To be honest I could run in IIS but I'm looking for optimal performance - Self Host avoids any sort of IIS overheads. Plus many more benefits. Also I *think* that if it's not self hosted it needs to sit inside an app, which I certainly want to avoid. I am actually surprised that I've not had any interest in the Q(s) haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any kind of constraint about where to deploy your service, any directory will do. As for the rest, you can install it like this:

```
installutil.exe SignalRService.exe
```

and to start it you can use either the *Services* panel under the *Administrative Tools*, or the command line (`net start/net stop` commands, see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490713.aspx))

SignalR will be alive as long as the service will (with proper error handling, of course).

You can get much more detail about all these things [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (for example about where you can find `installutil.exe`).

Comment: The problem is that installutil is to install locally with Visual Studio (developer cmd) cmd. This does not work when deploying without Visual Studio.

Comment: Not true, `installutil.exe` comes with the .NET framework directly, which of course you must have installed on the server. The article I mentioned tells you where you can find it, which is where .NET lives.

Comment: Well I hold my hand up to be mistaken. I shall check it out and get back to you. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Wasp...Tried out the links etc, having issues installing:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30150285/windows-service-start-failure-for-self-hosted-signalr